# Call $t function in nuxt.js plugin

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

I am building a nuxt.js application. So my plan is to inject helper object and functions that are being reused to context.

So I created a plugin

```
export default (context) => {
     const { $t } = context.app;

     const validators = {
      firstNameRules: [
         v => !!v || $t('formValidation.NO_FIRST_NAME'),
         v => v.length < 128 || $t('formValidation.INVALID_FIRST_NAME_TOO_LONG')
       ]
     };

     context.$formValidators = validators;
}
```

The object is injected to context correctly and I can access rules where I want. 
However trying to run the function $t brings me to error

```
Cannot read property '_t' of undefined
```

So basically I would like to run $t function and to get localized message when stuff happens. Is that possible and if yes, how?

[image: errror compiling message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to solve it eventually.

So the thing is in the way `this` behaves in JS

I changed the code to be like this:

```
export default function(context) {
  function getValidators() {
    return {
      firstNameRules: [
        v => !!v || this.$t('formValidation.NO_FIRST_NAME'),
        v => v.length < 128 || this.$t('formValidation.INVALID_FIRST_NAME_TOO_LONG')
      ]
    };
  }

  Vue.prototype.$formValidators = getValidators;
  context.$formValidators = getValidators;
}
```

And then from my component/page

```
data() {
  const { firstNameRules } = this.$formValidators();
}
```

Doing things like that, `this` is preserved all the way down to the `$t` function

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an `inject`:

```
export default (context, inject) => {
  const { $t } = context.app;
  const validators = {
    firstNameRules: [
      v => !!v || $t('formValidation.NO_FIRST_NAME'),
      v => v.length < 128 || $t('formValidation.INVALID_FIRST_NAME_TOO_LONG')
    ]
  };

  context.$formValidators = validators;
  inject('formValidators', validators);
};
```

Comment: Nope, this does not change anything. But I did manage to solve things. `this` behavior was problematic